# Codeigniter: Ajax -> MySql -> DIV

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. Вопрос от совсем новичка,сильно глупый,но поиск толком ничего не дал. Сильно не ругайте, только в начале пути. Есть несколько div с присвоенным `<p id='divtext/divtitle/divimg'></p>`. Контроллер, модель, MySql БД соответственно. Полный массив данных через `$query = $this->db->get('main');`получаю, через print_r вывожу, всё в порядке. Вопрос. В БД 5 строк на 6 столбцов, на странице 5 кнопок. Как посредством ajax при нажатии кнопки реализовать получение выборки отдельной строки из бд по полю "id" и отправить в div. Допустим , первая кнопка делает выборку по id=1 и передаёт отдельные столбцы этой строки в разные div элементы. Заранее большое вам спасибо.

Comment: Для начала надо без ajax написать, а потом все просто.